# How do I stop tab from being electric in Text mode?

Tags: formatting, tabs

When editing a plain-text document in Text mode when I press tab emacs inserts spaces until the cursor appears directly beneath the beginning of a word it finds in the line above.

I don't want it to do this. What I want is for the tab key to columnise the cursor position and therefore to align the cursor with the next preset tab-stop, ignoring text in the preceding line, much as a conventional mechanical manual typewriter does.

What setting do I need to change for tab to behave like a conventional manual typewriter in Text mode?

Comment: This question might be a duplicate - maybe someone can find that. (There are _lots_ of hits when I search for `tab-to-tab-stop`, but a quick check didn't find a good dup.)

Comment: I also looked first, and didn't find a duplicate. I wouldn't have thought to search for "tab-to-tab-stop". If there is a duplicate then neither you nor I found it, even after looking.

Comment: Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What TAB does now is `indent-for-tab-command`. What you want is `tab-to-tab-stop`.
The latter is available at `M-i`, so one option is to learn to use that.

To always bind TAB to run that command in Text mode, you can put

```
(add-hook 'text-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key text-mode-map "\t" 'tab-to-tab-stop)))
```

in your init file.

Comment: +1 for the explanation. But no need for the hook addition. Just `(define-key ...)` is sufficient.

Comment: @pst, thanks. M-i is the definitely the behaviour I described. Thank you for the additional information too.